# Where is the "comfort relay" in a BMW 1992 325i AUTO?

Tags: electrical, bmw

Please advise where the Comfort Relay is positioned in my car which is right-hand drive. The problem is that the windows and sunroof do not open or close.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.justanswer.com/bmw/2m5y4-comfort-relay-92-325i.html) help? (Click on "this".)

Comment: Note that that customer had the same problem and ended the conversation with: "It turned out it was the fuse for the door locks".

Answer (score 1):

Following the link in [this comment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/where-is-the-comfort-relay-in-a-bmw-1992-325i-auto#comment9183_7380), the Comfort Relay can be found under left side of the the dashboard

[image: Diagram]

Listed as "Relay Panel" in the diagram below:

[image: Location]